# Riding and weight loss

Tags: weight

I previously read a post about weight loss and cycling, where the response was a link to another forum with lots of before and after pictures. Does anyone know that link? I did run a search before asking this here.

Comment: Your question is too vague for any proper answer and lacks content or a specific question in terms of identification, I'm afraid you aren't going to get much of help here. Take a __[tour]__ to learn what this site is about.

Comment: Im looking for a thread about weight loss. Im also looking for a thread with before and after pictures thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular belief, cycling is not a "magic bullet" for weight loss.  I know some hefty cyclists that ride much more than the average person (I am one of them).

Speaking in very broad terms, weight loss comes primarily from adjusting one's diet more-so than activity levels.  Increasing activity simply helps the progress that you are making with your diet.

It is ENTIRELY possible to out-eat any gains you get from exercise.  Trust me, I know from first-hand experience :D